# Catching console.log in node.js?

Tags: node.js, module, callback

Is there a way that I can catch eventual console output caused by `console.log(...)`  within node.js to prevent cloggering the terminal whilst unit testing a module?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

module.js:

```
module.exports = function() {
    console.log("foo");
}
```

program:

```
console.log = function() {};
mod = require("./module");
mod();
// Look ma no output!
```

**Edit:** Obviously you can collect the log messages for later if you wish:

```
var log = [];
console.log = function() {
    log.push([].slice.call(arguments));
};
```

Answer (score 30):

A better way could be to directly hook up the output you to need to catch data of, because with Linus method if some module write directly to stdout with `process.stdout.write('foo')` for example, it wont be caught.

```
var logs = [],

hook_stream = function(_stream, fn) {
    // Reference default write method
    var old_write = _stream.write;
    // _stream now write with our shiny function
    _stream.write = fn;

    return function() {
        // reset to the default write method
        _stream.write = old_write;
    };
},

// hook up standard output
unhook_stdout = hook_stream(process.stdout, function(string, encoding, fd) {
    logs.push(string);
});

// goes to our custom write method
console.log('foo');
console.log('bar');

unhook_stdout();

console.log('Not hooked anymore.');

// Now do what you want with logs stored by the hook
logs.forEach(function(_log) {
    console.log('logged: ' + _log);
});
```

**EDIT**

`console.log()` ends its output with a newline, you may want to strip it so you'd better write:

```
_stream.write = function(string, encoding, fd) {
    var new_str = string.replace(/\n$/, '');
    fn(new_str, encoding, fd);
};
```

**EDIT**

Improved, generic way to do this on any method of any object with async support [See the gist](https://gist.github.com/2006752).

Answer (score 6):

[capture-console](https://www.npmjs.com/package/capture-console) solves this problem nicely.

```
var capcon = require('capture-console');

var stderr = capcon.captureStderr(function scope() {
  // whatever is done in here has stderr captured,
  // the return value is a string containing stderr
});

var stdout = capcon.captureStdout(function scope() {
  // whatever is done in here has stdout captured,
  // the return value is a string containing stdout
});
```

and later

> ## Intercepting
>
> You should be aware that all `capture` functions will still pass the values through to the main stdio `write()` functions, so logging will still go to your standard IO devices.
>
> If this is not desirable, you can use the `intercept` functions. These functions are literally `s/capture/intercept` when compared to those shown above, and the only difference is that calls aren't forwarded through to the base implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add the following snippet to your code will let you catch the logs and still print it in the console:

```
var log = [];
console.log = function(d) {
    log.push(d);
    process.stdout.write(d + '\n');
};
```

Comment: Nice. Worked for my use case which is to read the stdout.