# How to read last line in a terminal console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to read printed last line in a console?

I am printing a line using

```
process.stdout.write("Hello World");
```

How to check printed last line? Example, if my last line has word "World", then I want to print "World is Beautiful" in next line.

Comment: Are you passing variables to different scripts using the console?

Comment: No, I am not!..

Comment: Then why not also save what you are printing in variables and passing those variables instead of reading the things you're outputting?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609393/catching-console-log-in-node-js

Answer (score 1):

Store your printed line in a variable before writing to screen and use the variable value to influence your new value and/or write . The variable will be available independent of the output.

Answer (score -1):

I hope that I am understanding you correctly. This code will enable you to catch the logs you have printed:

```
var log = [];
console.log = function(d) {
    log.push(d);
    process.stdout.write(d + '\n');
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but this may not be what I am looking for, sorry if I havent conveyed it properly, I'll try my best to explain, I have printed "Hello world" in terminal console using process.stdout now I want print some word based on my previous/last printed line. I think its something to do with process.stdin