# Hook to console.log in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm looking to hook to console.log in electron.
I tried following the steps as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9624028/2091948
While the above works well in node.js, this same approach doesn't work in electron (which in-turn is node.js based)

How can I achieve this in electron?
I need to capture all calls to console.log, and console.error, so that I can use the module `electron-log`(https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-log) to hook to all console.log, and console.error calls.

Answer (score 3):

I think this could be done just via overriding `console.log` or `console.error` like this:

```
var log = require("electron-log");

console.log = function (message) {
  log.info(message);
}
console.error = function (message) {
  log.error(message);
}
```

Alternatively, if you like to preserve the old functions and/or store all messages in an array for later use, you could use the following functions:

```
var log = require("electron-log"), msgInfo = [], msgErr = [];

// Preserve the old, built-in functions
console.log_old = console.log;
console.error_old = console.error;

console.log = function (message) {
  msgInfo.push(message);
  log.info(message);
}

console.error = function (message) {
  msgErr.push(message);
  log.error(message);
}
```

You can use these functions in a browser window, for the main process, the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609393/catching-console-log-in-node-js/9624028#9624028) you already mentioned should work with some adaptions:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/9624028, written by "kevin"
var logs = [],

hook_stream = function(_stream, fn) {
  // Reference default write method
  var old_write = _stream.write;
  // _stream now write with our shiny function
  _stream.write = fn;

  return function() {
    // reset to the default write method
    _stream.write = old_write;
  };
},

// hook up standard output
unhook_stdout = hook_stream(process.stdout, function(string, encoding, fd) {
  logs.push(string);
}),

// require electron-log
log = require("electron-log");

// goes to our custom write method
console.log('foo');
console.log('bar');

unhook_stdout();

console.log('Not hooked anymore.');

// Now do what you want with logs stored by the hook
logs.forEach(function(_log) {
  // Either log the contents of the message array...
  //console.log('logged: ' + _log);

  // ...or use electron-log to actually log them.
  log.info(_log);
});
```

This code will work in the main process, because there NodeJS creates the stream to `stdout`. In the renderer process you will have to use the functions I mentioned above, because Electron doesn't create any stream but rather lets Chromium log all messages to it's Developer Console.

Comment: One thing which this solution lacks is, it loses the information on line number which printed the information. That was possible in node.js as per this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9624028/2091948

Comment: That's right, but since I don't think that the BrowserWindow's `console.log` creates a stream (what `console.log` in the main process does using `stdout`), I don't see how this could be implemented...

Comment: I see. So do you have a suggestion how it could be down from main process in electron?
I suppose by BrowserWindow's `console.log`, you mean the renderer process.

Comment: Correct. BrowserWindow is executed on the renderer process. For the main process, you can use the code you already mentioned, but replace the `logs.push()` line with the log function. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook up to the `console-message` event of the `WebContent` object (available from the `webContent` property on `BrowserView` and `BrowserWindow`).

Note that it only provides it as a *string* so if you are loggign an object it will be received as `[object Object]`

For more info see [the docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-console-message)