# What is the actual output of console.log(error) and how do I get the exact same output as a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, error-handling, console.log

In a **Node.js** project using Typescript and targeting ES2020, I'm using a custom Error class like this:

```
class InvalidParamsError extends Error {
}

try {
  throw new InvalidParamsError();
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof Error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(error.message); // Different output
    console.log(error.stack); // Different output
    console.log(error.toString()); // Different output
  }
}
```

The output I get in the console is:

```
InvalidParamsError
    at REPL11:2:13
    at ...

Error
    at REPL11:2:13
    at ...
Error
undefined
```

**How can I get this very same output as a string without having to print it to the console?**

`error.message`, `error.stack` and `error.toString()` all return different strings, and none of them show `InvalidParamsError` as part of the output, showing a generic `Error` instead. I know I could fix this manually setting the `name` of the `InvalidParamsError` in the constructor, but even then I'm unable to get exactly the same output as `console.log(error)` as a string.

I tried looking at [Node.js' console source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/console/constructor.js) but couldn't find any answer.

I'm targeting ES2020 so I don't think this is related with [previous Typescript issues when extending built-ins like Error](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/main/Breaking-Changes.md#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work).

Comment: `error.toString()`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus that's the point of the post, that produces a different output.

Comment: Is there an `error.type`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus have you even read the content of the question? `error.toString()` does not include `InvalidParamsError` as part of the output text, I already tried that. And no, property 'type' does not exist in type 'Error'.

Comment: [MDN/Error#custom_error_types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#custom_error_types)

Comment: Does this answer your question [Catching console.log in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609393/catching-console-log-in-node-js)?

Comment: @BenWheeler let me know if my answer is canonical enough

Answer (score 1):

> I tried looking at [Node.js' console source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/console/constructor.js) but couldn't find any answer.

In node.js [`console.log`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#consolelogdata-args) does use [`util.format`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilformatformat-args) which in turn defers to [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-options). The code of that function jumps through some hoops but eventually [calls](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/78855fdefee77ea13df9fa1887dc650b849a4f6d/lib/internal/util/inspect.js#L985) the [`formatError` function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/78855fdefee77ea13df9fa1887dc650b849a4f6d/lib/internal/util/inspect.js#L1367-L1433) which creates the output you are looking for.

In particular, the bit about using the `InvalidParamsError` name happens in [`improveStack`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/78855fdefee77ea13df9fa1887dc650b849a4f6d/lib/internal/util/inspect.js#L1270-L1301), where it replaces the standard `error.name` that the `error.stack` starts with by the standard object inspection prefix (e.g. `Array(n)` or `Object`) created from [`getConstructorName`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/78855fdefee77ea13df9fa1887dc650b849a4f6d/lib/internal/util/inspect.js#L587-L633) and [`getPrefix`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/78855fdefee77ea13df9fa1887dc650b849a4f6d/lib/internal/util/inspect.js#L693-L705).

> How can I get this very same output as a string without having to print it to the console?

```
import { inspect } from 'node:util';

class InvalidParamsError extends Error {}

try {
  throw new InvalidParamsError();
} catch (error) {
  const string = inspect(error);
  …
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for the `format` util that `console` stdout methods use. Additionally you can extend the constructor to match the same arguments from the parent class. You can specify more if you'd like:

```
import { format } from 'node:util';

class InvalidParamsError extends Error {
  constructor(...params: Parameters<typeof Error>) {
    super(...params);
    this.name = 'InvalidParamsError';
  }
}

function thisFunctionThrows() {
  let outputString = '';
  try {
    // intellisense for constructor args!
    throw new InvalidParamsError('message', { cause: 'error cause' });
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      outputString = format(error);
    }
  }
  return outputString;
}

const errorString = thisFunctionThrows();
console.log(errorString);
```

added a name to function to ensure trace is correct

Answer (score -1):

i think this is what you are looking for:

```js
try {
  throw new InvalidParamsError();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(
    `Uncaught ${e.constructor.name}: ${e.message}\n${e.stack
      .split("\n")
      .filter((item) => item)
      .map((item) => "  " + item)
      .join("\n")}`
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To obtain the string version of such output:

```
if (error instanceof Error) {
    // remove the first line of the stack
    const errorStackLines = error.stack.split('\n')
    errorStackLines.splice(0,1)
  
    const stackWithoutErrorName = stackLines.join('\n')
    const errorName = error.constructor.name
    const { message, stack } = error

    const errorString = `${errorName}\n${stackWithoutErrorName}\n${message}\n${stack}\n${error.toString()}`

    return errorString
}
```

Answer (score -2):

One possible way to get the same output as console.log(error) as a string is to use the `util.format()` function from the Node.js `util` module. This function returns a formatted string using the same rules as `console.log()`.

For example, you can write:

```
const util = require(‘util’);
let errorString = util.format(error);
```

This will assign the same string as `console.log(error)` to the variable `errorString`.

Another possible way is to use the `console.log()` function itself, but redirect its output to a writable stream instead of the standard output. For example, you can write:

```js
const { Writable } = require(‘stream’);
let errorString = ‘’;
const stream = new Writable({
  write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    errorString += chunk.toString(); callback();
  }
});
console.log(error, stream);
```

This will append the same string as `console.log(error)` to the variable `errorString`.

I hope this helps you with your project.

: [util.format(object[, …args]) | Node.js v17.1.0 Documentation] : [Console | Node.js v17.1.0 Documentation]

Comment: Please use [appropriate formatting](/help/formatting), and [drop greetings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/183280)