# How to convert exception object (symbol) into readable string

Tags: node.js, typescript, exception, es6-modules, ts-node

Let's say, in `.ts` file you have syntax error and you load the app with `ts-node/esm`. `uncaughtException` will throw such exception:

```
> Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom)
```

What is the best way to turn it into readable string, because `err.toString ()` does not work?

[image]

Comment: Use `util.inspect(err)` instead of `err.toString()`

Comment: Notice that the exception *is not* a symbol, rather it is an object that *has* a symbol property

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77591436/1048572